# How to query post like normal search would do. within search.php page

Tags: categories, wp-query, query-posts, search

I have a costume search in a site i am making.

When a user search a certain term, i want to display category list with a count of how many posts are found with in that category.

I thought of a way but i have problems doing it.

1. in search.php in the loop  in `have_posts()`, i will add a line that check each post's category and create an array with those categories ... and just +1 each time a certain category repeat itself...... problem with that since pagination is in place, it will only find the categories for the current page while the remaining pages stay unaccounted for.

The fix for that is having another wp_query that just use the `s` term. without the pagination.

Problem with that is i dont know how to query wp for a certain term like a normal search would do. i though of using `query_posts` somehow but still unclear on how.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i did:

I run another query without pagination like this:

```
$newQuaryVars = '&posts_per_page=99999999999999&post_type=post';
$posts = query_posts($query_string .$newQuaryVars);
$categoriesList = array();
$categoriesAmounts = array();
```

Then in the `while have posts` i did the following:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $postCategories = get_the_category();
    if($postCategories){
        foreach($postCategories as $categoryInfo) {
            $categoriesAmounts[$categoryInfo->term_id]['amount']++;
            $categoriesList[$categoryInfo->term_id] = array( 
                'name' => $categoryInfo->name, 
                'url' => get_category_link( $categoryInfo->term_id ), 
                'amount' => $categoriesAmounts[$categoryInfo->term_id]['amount']
            );
        }
    }
endwhile;
```

Now i basically have an array with categories name / url and the amount of posts that fit the search term within the that category.

after that i just array_multisort it and displayed it.

Hope that helps anyone out there.

Comment: **Quadrillion, really??** :) That's a lot of posts! You might find `posts_per_page = -1` or `nopagination = true` query parameters useful if you want to disable pagination altogether!

Comment: Also plase don't use `query_posts`. `get_posts` will serve you better here - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts Anyway - congrats on taming your query and welcome on WPSE! :)

Comment: Thanks you both  michal mau, thanks for tips i've checked the link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the number of posts in a category...

```
$qry = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>2));
var_dump($qry->found_posts);
```

... but you could very easily have a lot of queries that way. Maybe something like this would help reduce that:

```
$catid = 1;
$qry = new WP_Query;
$cat_count = array();
if (!isset($cat_count['cat-'.$catid])) {
    $qry->query(array('cat'=>$catid));
    $cat_count['cat-'.$catid] = $qry->found_posts;
}
var_dump($cat_count)
```

At least it only runs a query the first time you encounter a category.

Comment: Nah you either missed what i am trying to achieve or thinking about a different idea.. my idea was lets say a search for "blue cars" is being preformed. i have car companies set as category, E.G dodge, ford, toyota..... all those companies have blue cars hence all 3 will come in the results. Now what i wanted is to show a list of all categories that has a post(in my example a blue car) and to count them. I found out how to do it will post an an answer in a sec.

Comment: "i want to display category list with a count of how many posts are found with in that category"-- Sorry, I don't see the different between that and what I just did, but glad you got it solved. If you want to further restrict the results just pass in the same values as used in the original query.

Comment: I've posted my answer if you like to take a look.